# MATLAB perform PCA on the correlation matrix

Tags: matlab, pca

As far as I understand, the [PCA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) is performed on the covariance matrix. Is there a way to use the correlation matrix instead? Does the `latent` output correspond to the eigenvalues?

Comment: according to that link the "latent" variable outputs the "principal component variances" - so no, it would not output all the eigenvalues, unless I guess they were all equal. As for the bit about correlation matrix, I'm not quite sure what you mean- but I'm guessing you mean between 2 sets of data, and I'm not really sure why you'd want to do that. Of course you could do it, but what the meaning of such a thing and what you would do with that information isn't clear to me. Could you explain more?

Comment: @ABC Do you know how can I get the eigenvalues?

Comment: Depends what you what the eigenvalues of and what you want to use them for. Generally PCA is used to reduce the amount of features in a dataset- either with the covariance of the data or else singular value decomposition to find the eigenvalues of this data- this tells you which features contribute the most info- and you zero out all the smaller eigenvalues, thus a reduction in features. If you want the eigenvalues of your data, you could just do an SVD and get them that way. Or you could use eig with either X (square) or X^TX (otherwise). I think you need to explain more what your goal is.

Comment: @ABC thanks for your answer. I'll try to explain myself better: I've move recently to MATLAB from SPSS. The thing is, I'm trying to obtain the same results when running a PCA in SPSS as in MATLAB. But the results are different. Here's a picture of the procedure in SPSS http://imgur.com/e4cW7iA

Comment: Ok, that clarified things :) I'm not sure why the two are coming out differently but I found through some digging that the correlation is a covariance matrix of the standardized data - its rescaled and shifted- so that would answer your initial question, you could look up those details and do the same normalization. If you're comparing the covariance methods in the two programs the reason could be that the implementations might vary. You can check out the matlab version by typing "edit <function>" in cmd. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's quite an old post, but I found the option to set it to compute PCA based on correlation matrix by specifying name-value pair `'VariableWeights','variance'`. You can refer to [pca-VariableWeights](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html#bth9ibe-VariableWeights)